# How to change the angle in surfaceview video recording?

Tags: android, android-layout, video, surfaceview, android-mediaplayer

I am recording a video using `surfaceview` with media recorder, it is recording but the display angle is 90 degree shifted it is not as the actual room record, that is if you are recording a room with my app, the display will be 90 degree shifted, the room ceiling will be on left and so ur room display. Any one help me to solve this to record in right angle video. Here is my code for your reference please check my codings here 

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >
<SurfaceView
  android:id="@+id/videoview" 
  android:layout_height="480px" android:layout_width="248dp"/>
<Button
  android:id="@+id/mybutton"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="REC"
  android:textSize="12dp"/> 
</RelativeLayout>`
```

`
  
here is my manifest file

```
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".SurfaceAngleRecActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>`
```

`and here is my code:

```
SurfaceAngleRecActivity.java                                        
public class SurfaceAngleRecActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
        {
        MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
        SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
        boolean recording;
        Button record;
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    boolean pausing = false;

        String PlayPath ="/sdcard/myvideo.mp4";
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
           initMediaRecorder();

           setContentView(R.layout.main);
           recording = false;


           SurfaceView myVideoView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
           surfaceHolder = myVideoView.getHolder();
           surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
           surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

           record=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);

           record.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(!recording)
               {
                   mediaRecorder.start();
                   recording = true;
                   //Stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   //Record.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                   record.setText("STOP");
                   //Play.setEnabled(false);
                   //Pause.setEnabled(false);
               }else
               {
                   mediaRecorder.stop();
                   mediaRecorder.release();
                   recording = false;
                   //Record.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   //Stop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                   //Record.setText("Record");
                   //Play.setEnabled(true);
                   //Pause.setEnabled(true);
                  // finish();
                   }
            }
        });

         }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            prepareMediaRecorder();
        }
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        private void initMediaRecorder()
           {
               mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
               mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
               //File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), PlayPath);
               CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile_HQ =CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
               mediaRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile_HQ);
               mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
               //mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(20, 20);
               //mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
           //mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Set max file size 5M
           }

           private void prepareMediaRecorder()
           {
               mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
               try
               {
                   mediaRecorder.prepare();
                   //mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(150, 200);
               }
               catch (IllegalStateException e) 
               {
                   //TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               catch (IOException e) 
               {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }

        }`
```

Answer (score 0):

change the orientation of your activity to landscape in Manifest.

`<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".SurfaceAngleRecActivity"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>`

Answer (score 0):

```
private void initMediaRecorder()
           {
               mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
               mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
               //File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), PlayPath);
               CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile_HQ =CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
               mediaRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile_HQ);
               mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
               **mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);**
           }
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setOrientationHint(int)